# Change color for hover state icon

Tags: html, css, icons, frontend

I have a side menu where inside the `<li>` tag I have an icon and a text.
When the mouse hovers, I want the icon to change to white. Right now only the text is changing to white.  I have read other posts but none worked.

Without hover [Normal state]

[image]

With hover [Hover state]

[image]

```
<li>
   <a href="#">
      <span class="icon-patient"></span>
   </a>
   <p>Paciente</p>
 </li>

li p {
font-size: 0.8em;
}

li span {
font-size: 1.8em;
}

li span:hover {
color: #fff;
}

li a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
}

ul li:hover {
background-color: #5D9CF3;
cursor: pointer;
color: #fff;
transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
transition-duration: 0.25s;
transition-property: background-color;
}
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what is going wrong with your code, but something that helps with debugging is the inspect tool in chrome (ctrl + shift + i).  You can go to individual elements of a page and manipulate them.  I use this all the time to do css work, as you can define the css you want, and see it real time (e.g. play with the css until it shows what you want when you hover, and dumping that into the hover definition).

Comment: also, off the top of my head, i would define one hover, for the outermost tag you want to target (e.g. the li) then nest the other tags inside it with the changes you want during the hover without the hover decorator.  Not sure if it will work, but it's the first thing I'd try

Comment: How can I achieve that? Sounds like a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
li:hover span {
 color: #fff!important;
}
```

If this won't help your icon is not a font.

If it's not working and it is a font we can try this solution:

```
li:hover a {
 color: #fff!important;
}
li:hover a span{
 color: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Is there a place so I could check the font?

Comment: It's an IcoMoon font I created. You can see a screenshot here https://imgur.com/a/KHnxDsM

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
li p {
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

li span {
  font-size: 1.8em;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: #5D9CF3;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transition-duration: 0.25s;
  transition-property: background-color;
}

li:hover a{
  text-decoration: none;
}

li:hover span {
  color: #fff;
}
```

My instinct about what is happening is that the css interpreter is looking at your li a:hover tag, for example, as "when li is not hovered, but a nested a is", which means li:hover is not being displayed.  These tags put the hover on li.  I think you can even hover on both, so li:hover a:hover, but haven't tried that myself.

Answer (score 0):

I used your code, and changed a little bit of the CSS, using the images provided, just for the hover effect.

Can you check if this is what you want to achieve?

https://codepen.io/alexandrecanijo/pen/jKzVwK

CSS would be like:

```
.link p {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.link span {
    font-size: 1.8em;
}

.link {
    display: block;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.link:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #5D9CF3;
    color: #fff;
    transition-duration: 0.25s;
    transition-property: background-color;
}

.icon-patient {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    display: block;
}

.icon-patient:before {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    content: "\f007";
}

.link:hover .icon-patient:before {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. It worked for me:

```
li a span:hover{
  color: #fff;
}
```